# Webpack 2 and Angular 1: exporting and import modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router

Hope to get some clarification on why the following doesn't work as expected, hopefully, it's something easy I may have overlooked. Without Webpack the current implementation works as expected.

Ideally, would like to keep current implementation, I feel registering the component/controller/etc should be done in its own file and just point to the relative module. But if this isn't best practice I'd also like to see another suggestion.

File root.module is where I define the root module and then in the root.component file I tack on the component to that module.

**Current implementation that doesn't import the module:**

```js
//root.component.js
'use strict';

var root = {
  template: require('./root.html')
};

module.exports = angular
  .module('root')
  .component('root', root);
'use strict';

//root.module.js
module.exports = angular
    .module('root', [
        require('./common').name,
        require('./components').name
    ]);
```

**If I do the following works and loads module as expected:**

```js
//root.component.js
'use strict';

var root = {
  template: require('./root.html')
};
module.exports = root;

//root.module.js
'use strict';

module.exports = angular
  .module('root', [
    require('./common').name,
    require('./components').name
  ])
  .component('root', require('./root.component'));
```

**Current directory tree:**

```html
├── ./src
│   ├── ./src/app
│   │   ├── ./src/app/app.less
│   │   ├── ./src/app/app.spec.js
│   │   ├── ./src/app/common
│   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/app.component.js
│   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/app.controller.js
│   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/app.html
│   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/footer
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/footer/app-footer.component.js
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/footer/app-footer.controller.js
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/footer/app-footer.html
│   │   │   │   └── ./src/app/common/footer/index.js
│   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/header
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/header/app-nav.component.js
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/header/app-nav.controller.js
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/header/app-nav.html
│   │   │   │   └── ./src/app/common/header/index.js
│   │   │   ├── ./src/app/common/index.js
│   │   │   └── ./src/app/common/sideBar
│   │   │       ├── ./src/app/common/sideBar/app-sidebar.component.js
│   │   │       ├── ./src/app/common/sideBar/app-sidebar.controller.js
│   │   │       ├── ./src/app/common/sideBar/app-sidebar.html
│   │   │       └── ./src/app/common/sideBar/index.js
│   │   ├── ./src/app/components
│   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/auth-form
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/auth-form/auth-form.component.js
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/auth-form/auth-form.controller.js
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/auth-form/auth-form.html
│   │   │   │   │   └── ./src/app/components/auth/auth-form/index.js
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/auth.service.js
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/auth.user.js
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/index.js
│   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/login
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/login/index.js
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/login/login.component.js
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ./src/app/components/auth/login/login.controller.js
│   │   │   │   │   └── ./src/app/components/auth/login/login.html
│   │   │   │   └── ./src/app/components/auth/register
│   │   │   │       ├── ./src/app/components/auth/register/index.js
│   │   │   │       ├── ./src/app/components/auth/register/register.component.js
│   │   │   │       ├── ./src/app/components/auth/register/register.controller.js
│   │   │   │       └── ./src/app/components/auth/register/register.html
│   │   │   └── ./src/app/components/index.js
│   │   ├── ./src/app/root.component.js
│   │   ├── ./src/app/root.html
│   │   └── ./src/app/root.module.js
│   └── ./src/index.ejs
└── ./webpack.config.js
```

Comment: In second snippet you have require('./root.component') . In first you don't. That's the obvious problem.

Comment: @estus, so there isn't a way to register and require the module the first way?

Comment: What do you mean? You need to `require` the file if you want its contents to be executed. If you don't `require` it, it won't be executed, this is very straightforward. If there is no `require('./root.component')` indeed behind the scenes, you need to add this line.

Comment: @estus if you'd like to answer the question showing what you mean, I'd like to reward the bounty to someone.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the problem you're having, but if it is indeed then it's quite simple. Though a better way is to not rely on single `root` module, as explained in the answer. It takes some time to figure out proper naming conventions for files and modules, but in the end it pays off and results in well-designed maintainable modular app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A file should be imported (or more precisely, `require`d, because the application relies on CommonJS modules) in order for it to be executed.

In the first snippet `root.module.js` doesn't contain `require('./root.component')`, so `root.component.js` is never executed.

It should be

```
//root.module.js
module.exports = anglar
  .module('root', [
    require('./common').name,
    require('./components').name
  ])
  .component('root', require('./root.component'));

require('./root.component');
```

Notice that `root.component.js` should be required after `root` module was defined, doing these in opposite order will result in `$injector:modulerr` error.

The proven way to eliminate race conditions and utilize modularity is to have one Angular module per one file. In this case it doesn't matter in which order the files are required. It is conventional to export and import module's `name` property from files that contain Angular modules:

```
//root.component.js
module.exports = angular.module('root.rootComponent', [])
  .component('root', {
    template: require('./root.html')
  })
  .name;

//root.module.js
var rootComponentModule = require('./root.component');
var commonModule = require('./common');
var componentsModule = require('./components');

module.exports = angular
    .module('root', [
        rootComponentModule,
        commonModule,
        componentsModule
    ])
    .name;
```

This recipe allows to maintain well-arranged deep hierarchy of highly modular units. This is beneficial for code reusing and testing.

Answer (score 3):

just want to share my approach with you. I'm using it for quite some time already and it works perfectly.

```
// src/components/foo/foo.component.js

import './foo.scss';

export class FooComponent {
    static NAME    = 'foo';
    static OPTIONS = {
        controller: FooComponent,
        template  : require('./foo.template.html'),
        bindings  : {},
    };

    constructor(FooService) {
        'ngInject';
        this._FooService = FooService;
    }

    $onInit() { /* ... */ }
    $onDestroy() { /* ... */ }
    /* ... */
}

// src/components/foo/foo.service.js

export class FooService {
    /* ... */
}


// src/components/foo/index.js

import { FooComponent } from './foo.component';
import { FooService } from './foo.service';

export const FOO_COMPONENT = angular.module('components.foo', [])
    .service('FooService', FooService)        
    .component(FooComponent.NAME, FooComponent.OPTIONS)
    .name;


// src/components/index.js

export { FOO_COMPONENT } from './foo';
export { BAR_COMPONENT } from './bar';
/* ... */


// src/app/users/index.js
import { CORE } from 'shared/core';

import { 
    FOO_COMPONENT,
    BAR_COMPONENT,
} from 'components';

import { USERS_LIST_COMPONENT } from './users-list';
import { USER_PROFILE_COMPONENT } from './user-profile';

/* ... */

export const USERS_MODULE = angular
    .module('app.users', [
        CORE,
        FOO_COMPONENT,
        BAR_COMPONENT,
        USERS_LIST_COMPONENT,
        USER_PROFILE_COMPONENT,
    ])
    .name


// src/app/index.js
import { USERS_MODULE } from './users';
import { PRODUCTS_MODULE } from './users';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export const APP_MODULE = angular
    .module('app', [
        USERS_MODULE,
        PRODUCTS_MODULE,
    ])
    .component(AppComponent.NAME, AppComponent.OPTIONS)
    .name;
```