# AngularJS Best Practice: Should components add themselves to AngularJS module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS project with a `shared` directory, in which there are several shared components.

```
- shared
    - index.js
    - alert
        - index.js
        - alert.component.js
        - alert.controller.js
        - alert.tpl.html
        - alert.scss
    - logging
        - index.js
        - logging.component.js
        - logging.controller.js
        - logging.tpl.html
        - logging.scss
```

The code is written in a modular way in ES6. So for instance `alert.component.js` might look like this:

```
import controller from './alert.controller'
export const Alert = {
    controller,
    templateUrl: 'shared/alert/alert.tpl.html'
};
```

I would like to have one AngularJS module called `shared` in which both components are defined. My question is on what level should I actually define the component. Should it be inside the component directory (`shared/alert/index.js`) or in the shared directory (`shared/index.js`).

In the first case, the file `shared/alert/index.js`, would look like this:

```
import { Alert } from './alert.component';
angular.module('shared').component('Alert', Alert);
```

And in the second case, the file would look like this:

```
export { Alert } from './alert.component';
```

And then both components would be defined in `shared/index.js`:

```
import { Alert } from './alert';
angular.module('shared').component('Alert', Alert);

import { Logging } from './logging';
angular.module('shared').component('Logging', Logging);
```

The first case seems a bit odd to me, since I kind of let the component add itself to the application. In the second case however I end up with a huge `index.js` file, if I have many shared components. So I was wondering what other up and down sides each of these approaches has and if there any best practices?

Comment: First I'd ask "What goal are you trying to achieve by using angular modules?"

Comment: @JCFord Could you clarify what you mean by that? How can I use AngularJS without using modules (or at least one module)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any 'best practice', the preferable way to do this is deduced from possible problems that can appear in this situation.

`angular.module('shared')` module getter is generally an antipattern, especially in modular environment. It should be evaluated after the module was defined with `angular.module('shared', [])` module setter. Doing the opposite will result in race condition and error.

In the first case importing `shared/alert/index.js` in tests or another module will result in error because `shared` module wasn't defined yet.

In the second case there will be no such problem, but only if `shared` module is defined in `shared/index.js`.

The approach that plays well with ES modules is [one module per file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43858286/3731501). The result is highly modular application with relatively low amount of boilerplate code. The benefits are reusability and testability, submodules can depend on each other but aren't coupled to `share`.

This is important consideration if some of submodules contain items that affect the entire application - decorators, config/run blocks, third-party modules that contain them (router).

Comment: Thank you, that is an interesting approach. I would be a bit concerned however, that it becomes a very tedious task, to define all the dependencies for these very small modules. Would this not be a lot of (unnecessary) extra effort?

Comment: This always depends on what happens in your code and how you intend to use it. If you reuse components separately in other projects, coupling to `shared` will be an obstacle. If some of those units contain the said *items that affect the entire application*, you'll be unable to execute isolated tests. In general, a single `export default angular.module(...).component(...).name` line per each index file is not a big price for a neat app.